# Can this be done by skinning?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am working on DNN 4.09.03. I want to modify the look and feel of a links module. I know how to change the outer looks with containers, but I want achieve a mouseover effect for the links itself.

Looking closely it appears that the links are placed into a table datacell. I want to set the background of that cell to and image, and on mouseover swap it for another image. Can this be done with skinning?

If not, I need some assistance in extending/customising the links module source. I need to know how to set up the development environment to do this first. I have the DotNetNuke solution (with source code) working in VS2008. How do I integrate the source of the links module, so i can customise it (and rename - maybe mylinks)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this by containers. If you can do it by any chance, I bet doing it by modifying the code is easier. You have to remember that you might have problems upgrading the links module in future if you modify it.

Just add the Links module to DNN VS2008 solution as a web application. You can do whatever change you won't to do in it. And then use a nant script to just package it and copy to DNN/Install/Modules folder. And then hit the DNN installation URL:
   `http://<dnn_url>/Install/Install.aspx?mode=installresources`

Alternatively you can write some post-build commands in VS2008 it self to copy stuff. Have a look at the existing modules and where each different part files of a module (.ascx, .dnn, .sqldataprovider) is stored in DNN after installation.

Comment: It's just a scripting language for Building projects. It can zip and copy stuff (beside many other things). 
'http://nant.sourceforge.net/'

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with some creative CSS and maybe even a little jQuery - i did a lot of this sort of thing for the Blog module without having to touch the core module -